# Multiple document.onload functions in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a chrome extension and i have a requirement as below.

There are 2 content scripts that has to be executed and both the content scripts has document.onload function. when the extension is loaded only one among the 2 content scripts are executing.

In Detail:
say 1.js is a content script that has to be extecuted when xyz.com page is opened.
2.js is another content script that has to be executed on xyz.com,abc.com,..and so on.

Issue :
When xyz.com page is loaded, if 2.js gets triggered initailly, content in 1.js is not getting executed and vice versa.

Is there any workaround for this situation ?

Please let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: You don't need document.onload usually since the content scripts run after this DOM event by default. The only case you might need it is when you have run_at: document_start, in which case you need to use document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback) or same for `window` and `'load'`.

Answer (score 0):

Only one is being triggered because one is overriding the other. Try using **addEventListener** instead:

```
document.body.addEventListener('load', function() {
   // your code
});
```

Setting this multiple times should not override the previous reference like the onLoad function did.

In your script files, you may need to wrap this in a self invoking function to ensure it is set before the body is loaded.

```
(function() {
    document.body.addEventListener('load', function() { 
        console.log('Inside the 1.js page'); 
        fillDetails(); 
    }); 
})();
```

Comment: Hi Eric, if the situation is document.body.onload function, this is not helping any more. the event listener is not even getting triggered when i used it near body.onload function.  should i need to use a different event listener in this scenario ?

Comment: @VinayGurram Did you try document.body.addEventListener ?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of where you inserted this? Just want to get some context.

Comment: In 1.js page -

document.body.addEventListener('load', function() {
 console.log('Inside the 1.js page');
 fillDetails();
});

In 2.js page -

document.body.addEventListener('load', function() {
console.log('Inside the 2.js page');
fillIDeatils();
});

Comment: Try using jquery ->   $( document ).ready(function() {
   console.log( "ready!" );
});

Comment: I edited my original post. Try wrapping it in a self invoking function.

Comment: IIFE has nothing to do with the execution order. The problem is that document body doesn't have this event. IIRC it's triggered on `window`. And DOMContentLoaded is triggered on `document`.